# Mouse event not working when tool tips come over button

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jbutton

I have a problem in my Java application has so many tool tips. Sometimes tool tip covers the button and I cannot click because it covers.

Do we have a way to make tool tip transparent to mouse event? Then I can click the button even if the tool tip covers it.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: You shouldn't be using a `MouseListener` with a button...

Comment: Our tool tips stays 1 minute.That is our customer requirement.So any way to to click the button through tool tip ?

Comment: *"Our tool tips stays 1 minute."*  OK, but I'll bet that is not the problem.  As a test, remove the long time and try to click the button 'through the tool tip'.  I'd bet it will still fail.  Post an MCVE like @mKorbel advised, so we can work out what is going wrong.  Otherwise we can only [guess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28494610/418556) 'broken code'..

Comment: @Prabhath use JWindow with a Swing.Timer instead of

Answer (score 1):

Since this source demonstrates how to create tool tips for buttons that can be 'clicked through', I guess the solution to the problem is 'change whatever is different in your code'.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TooltipButtonClickTest {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    TooltipButtonClickTest() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,8,2,2));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("action command: " + e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };
        int sz = 15;
        Insets pad = new Insets(sz,sz,sz,sz);
        for (int i=1; i<65; i++) {
            JButton b = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            b.setMargin(pad);
            b.setToolTipText("This is tool tip " +String.valueOf(i));
            b.addActionListener(listener);
            ui.add(b);
        }
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                TooltipButtonClickTest o = new TooltipButtonClickTest();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("???");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: When we move frame closer to task bar tool tips position bit lifted.Then mouse click not work.

Comment: Still I have the problem.Can any one tell a way to put tool tip on top of the component instead of appearing bottom ?

Comment: Well, you were advised 20 days ago to post an MCVE/SSCCE.  If you cannot manage that, don't expect more help.

Answer (score 0):

Tool tip moves little bit upwards if location not enough in the bottom.

```
public static Point getToolTipLocation(JComponent component)
{
  Point point = component.getLocationOnScreen();
  int componentHeight = component.getHeight();
  int screenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
  Insets scnMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(component.getGraphicsConfiguration());
  int taskBarSize = scnMax.bottom;

  FontMetrics metrics = component.getFontMetrics(component.getFont());
  int height = metrics.getHeight();
  int lines = 1;

  //Tool tip location shifted to up if screen does not have space in the bottom.
  if (point.y + componentHeight + taskBarSize + (height * lines) > screenHeight)
  {
    int xPos = component.getWidth() / 2;
    return new Point(xPos, -((height * lines) + 25));
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then override the **getToolTipLocation()** method in JButton and call above method works fine for me.